# Struck with Switch, reducing cyclomatic complexity java

Tags: java, oop, java-8

while working with java i was stuck in a weird situation, lets start with code first.

```
public static String constructMessage(final String reason, final String xId,
        final String yId, final IonStruct metadataStruct) throws DataSanityException {
    String message = "";
        switch (reason) {
            case "NOT_ACTIVE":
                if (xId != null) {
                    message = String.format("Y %s X %s not active: status is inactive%n", yId, xId);
                } else {
                    message = String.format("Y %s not active: status is inactive%n", yId);
                }
                break;
            case "PRICE_GONE":
                if (metadataStruct.containsKey("applied")) {
                    final String applied = metadataStruct.get("applied");
                    if (applied.equals("single")) {
                        message = String.format("X %s is not active. price for the X is gone. "
                                + "Y price %s for an X should not be gone by %s.%n", xId,
                                metadataStruct.get("yPrice"), metadataStruct.get("zPrice"));
                    } else {
                        if (metadataStruct.get("gonePeriod").equals("gonegone")) {
                            message = String.format("Y price is %s whereas the gone price is %s."
                                    + " Y price for an X should be at least %s%% lower than gone.%n",
                                    metadataStruct.get(yPrice), metadataStruct.get(zPrice), metadataStruct.get("xyzPrice"));
                        } else {
                            message = String.format("Y price %s for an X should be at least %s%% lower than gone price %s in last %s days.%n",
                                    metadataStruct.get(yPrice), metadataStruct.get("mpqPrice"), metadataStruct.get(lpzPrice),
                                    metadataStruct.get("numberOfDays"));
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    message = String.format(
                            "X %s in Y %s is not active. is %s%%, min mpux is %s%%. ", xId,
                            yId, metadataStruct.get("lpux"), metadataStruct.get("mpxPrice"));
                }
                break;

         and so on ----------- around 20 cases.
         default:
                message = "";
                break;
}
```

there are 20 cases like this in the complete switch with different messages and different variables used in each of the cases.
And the depth of ifs is also upto 3 in some of the switches.

So the cyclomatic complexity is coming 29(too high), so i want to refactor the code with low cyclomatic complexity and better readability.

Any Suggestion ?

Comment: Use enums instead?

Comment: That doesn't look like it compiles. Where do you declare the `applied` in `if(applied.equals...)`?

Comment: @kayaman the complexity will still be the same, so do readability.

Comment: @daniu its just the dummy code, and which adding this i missed that edited now, the real code i have is working.

Comment: @whishky I didn't mean "change `String` to `enum` and don't change anything else".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Martin Fowler's Refactoring book [image]

I can suggest following refactoring method:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Refactoring {

    private static class IonStruct {};

    private static interface MessageBuilder {
        String  build(final String xId,final String yId, final IonStruct metadataStruct);
    }


    private static class NotActiveMessageBuilder implements MessageBuilder {

        private static final String YX_NON_ACTIVE_FMT = "Y %s X %s not active: status is inactive%n;";
        private static final String Y_NON_ACTIVE_FMT = "Y %s not active: status is inactive%n";

        @Override
        public String build(String xId, String yId, IonStruct metadataStruct) {
            return (xId != null) ? String.format(YX_NON_ACTIVE_FMT, yId, xId) : String.format(Y_NON_ACTIVE_FMT, yId) ;
        }

    }

    private static enum MessageTypeChine
    {
        instance();
        private final Map<String,MessageBuilder> builders;
        private MessageTypeChine() {
            this.builders = new HashMap<>();
            this.builders.put("NOT_ACTIVE", new NotActiveMessageBuilder());
        }

        public String constructMessage(final String reason, final String xId,
                final String yId, final IonStruct metadataStruct) {
            MessageBuilder builder = this.builders.get(reason);
            if(null != builder)
                return builder.build(xId, yId, metadataStruct);

            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Message type is not supported");
        }
    }


    public static String constructMessage(final String reason, final String xId,
            final String yId, final IonStruct metadataStruct) {
        return MessageTypeChine.instance.constructMessage(reason, xId, yId, metadataStruct);
    }

}
```

Comment: It is the same reasoning behind the Open-Closed Principle of SOLID programming.

Comment: thats the kind of mechenism i was looking for. thanks

Comment: This is kind of [Strategy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern). BWT. If you have Spring, or Guice  or any another IoCTL you'd better use it instead of self made Singleton ...

Comment: just one thing why enums ? why not just simple factory methods ?

Comment: In my case enum is "Singleton of Bloch" nothing else.

Comment: what is this instance() ? and why we need this ? why don't just make the enum static ?

Comment: Check this http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1216151&seqNum=3

Answer (score 7):

With "use `enum`s instead", Kayaman means something like:

```
interface MessageGenerator {
    String getMessage(String xId, String yId, IonStruct metadataStruct);
}

enum Reason implements MessageGenerator {
    NOT_ACTIVE((xId, yId, unused) -> 
        (xId != null) ? String.format("Y %s X %s not active: status is inactive%n", yId, xId)
                      : String.format("Y %s not active: status is inactive%n", yId)
    }),
    PRICE_GONE(...),
    DEFAULT(xId, yId, metadataStruct) -> 
        String.format("X %s in Y %s is not active. is %s%%, min mpux is %s%%. ", 
        xId, yId, metadataStruct.get("lpux"), metadataStruct.get("mpxPrice")));

    private MessageGenerator delegate;
    private Reason(MessageGenerator delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }
    // implement MessageGenerator interface by delegation
    public String getMessage(String xId, String yId, IonStruct metadataStruct) {
        return delegate.getMessage(xId, yId, metadataStruct);
    }

    public static Reason findReason(String reason) {
        Reason result = DEFAULT;
        try {
            result = valueOf(reason);
        } catch (RuntimeException ex) {}
        return result;
    }
}
```

and you can do

```
String constructMessage(String reason, final String xId,
    final String yId, final IonStruct metadataStruct) {
    Reason r = Reason.findReason(reason);
    return r.getMessage(xId, yId, metadataStruct);
}
```

Comment: Good answer, but just out of curiosity what's the advantage of using a delegate as opposed to defining the `getMessage` method for each enum instance?

Comment: i think with this one as well no of branches is still the same. its just we are having 20 enums in place of switches.

Comment: Please use `Reason r = Reason.valueOf(reason)` instead of the mysterious `findReason()`.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException You can explicitly declare it per enum value, but this way you can refer to implementations in other classes (a utility class containing static methods with the implementations maybe to keep the enum itself tidy). It does boil down to taste I guess.

Comment: @CostiCiudatu Well since there's a default case, I'd rather use a specific method catching the "value not available case" instead of handling it everywhere. I added an implementation to the answer to make it less elusive ;)

Comment: @whishky The amount of values in an enum does not increase cyclomatic complexity of the code.

Comment: @daniu and what about the code readability, does it makes sense to have 20 enums with their respective methods ?

Comment: and if you have to choose between using Factory method or enums which one you will favor and why ?

Comment: @whishky It depends how often you use this `Reason` concept throughout your code. If you use it often, you probably want to get the `MessageCreation` logic out of the `enum`, maybe by maintaining a `Map<Reason, MessageGenerator>` accessed by something like `getMessageGeneratorByReason(String reason)`. It really depends.

Comment: @daniu its will be used frequently because i'll have a list of reasons and for each reason i have to construct a message.