# Create instance in class or get object from outside, which on is true?

Tags: java, oop, solid-principles

I studied about **SOLID** Principle and created a question for me about it.
you suppose that we need a `Tea` Object in `Mug` class, now is this better than create a instance from `Tea` in `Mug` class or pass from outside through `Constructor` or `setter` method.

which on is true?

example:

```
class Mug {

    private Tea tea;

    public Mug(){
       this.tea = new Tea();
    }

    public boolean isFull(){
       return this.tea.value != 10;
    }
}
```

or

```
class Mug {

    private Tea tea;

    public Mug(Tea tea){
       this.tea = tea;
    }

   // public void setTea(Tea tea){
   //    this.tea = tea;
   // }

    public boolean isFull(){
       return this.team.value != 10;
    }
}
```

use:

```
  public class Test {

   static void main(String[] args){
       Mug mug = new Mug();
       //or
       Mug mug = new Mug(new Tea());
  }
}
```

which one is better?

*NOTE*: Suppose that `Mug` support only `Tea` object in our program.

Comment: Both violate SOLID . Your class should depend upon the abstractions which should be injected from outside. Tea is not an abstraction but it's a concrete implementation.

Comment: Mug is coupled with implementation of Tea. Tea should implement an interface and Mug should depend upon that interface.

Comment: @nits.kk supposes that mug support only tea in our program.

Comment: I edited my answer after your comment. Hope it helps

Comment: @nits.kk thanks my friend

Comment: You can accept my answer if it's helpful in resolving your doubts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of your cases violate SOLID.

Your each concrete implementation (concrete class) should only be dependent upon Abstractions.
in your case Tea is not an abstraction. Mug has tight coupling with Tea. Below is a possible way to code it.

```
public interface ITea{
     //tea related methods which you think should be exposed to outside world. Also all implementation of ITea must support these method (L in SOLID)
 }

public class Tea implements ITea{
  // Implement the contract methods from ITea
}

public class Mug {
    private ITea tea;
    // Have constructor or setter to inject concrete implementation. Setter will provide you capability to modify behavioral at run time.
 }
```

EDIT:
1. If we are sure there is only one possible implementation Of tea. Then also interface is better as concrete implementations are hard to mock and hence makes unit testing is difficult.

2. Avoid using enums for setting type. Enums inject switch cases and in future if a case is added all such switch cases needs to be modified leading to violation of O in SOLID.

If a case is added you have to modify existing code and in case you forget to add a case somewhere it leads to unexpected errors. (It violates OCP. Instead of enums put logic in specific implementation, have common interface and specific implementation). Also if we implement the case specific logic in individual instances of enum then the enum file will become gigantic. Instead if we have specific logic in individual concrete classes implementing common interface makes the user code easy as it can be injected with concrete classes in a polymorphic way.

p.s. this answer is about following the principles and it's not always possible to do so. It's fine to violate the principle but we must *know that we are violating it, and have a very good reason to do  so*.

Comment: `avoid enums for setting type... enums inject switch case` - the opposite is true. If you have an enum implementing a switch logic, you can add cases to all corresponding switches by just introducing a new enum value.

Comment: If a case is added you have to modify existing code and in case you forget to add a case somewhere it leads to unexpected errors. It violates OCP. Instead of enums put logic in specific implementation, have common interface and specific implementation.

Comment: No, implementing the logic in the `enum` is the proper way of getting rid of a switch altogether. It's then refactored into a call of the switch's actual value's method. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49690102/struck-with-switch-reducing-cyclomatic-complexity-java/49690242#49690242

Comment: For small logic enums instances are good but imagine full fledged  business logic then one enum in a single file with all the instances with their individual logic will be a gigantic file

Answer (score 0):

I would use the second one where possible, injecting a classes dependencies, take this example where the `Tea` constructor requires more information:

```
class Mug {

    private Tea tea;

    public Mug(int temperature) {
        this.tea = new Tea(temperature);
    }

    public boolean isFull() {
        return tea.value != 10;
    }
}
```

See how ugly that is that `Mug`'s constructor now needs information only used by `Tea`'s constructor.

But as it stands I would say that neither of your examples violates any SOLID principle.

There is nothing that says you can't create a new object inside another and nothing that says you must create abstractions.

Here would be a real violation in this area:

```
class Mug { // VIOLATION

    private Tea tea;
    private Coffee coffee;

    public Mug(boolean tea) {
        if (tea) {
            this.tea = new Tea();
        } else {
            this.coffee = new Coffee();
        }
    }

    public boolean isFull() {
        return tea.value != 10 || coffee.value != 10;
    }
}
```

The class depends upon multiple similar classes. Compare to:

```
class Mug {

    private Liquid liquid;

    public Mug(Liquid liquid) {
        this.liquid = liquid;
    }

    public boolean isFull() {
        return liquid.getVolume() != 10;
    }
}

interface Liquid {
    int getVolume();
}

class Tea implements Liquid {

    private int volume;

    @Override
    public int getVolume() {
        return volume;
    }
}

class Coffee implements Liquid {

    private int volume;

    @Override
    public int getVolume() {
        return volume;
    }
}
```

But as you only have one thing that can go in a `Mug` there is no violation and no need for an abstraction. In general, never write any code that doesn't solve a problem.

And never create an abstraction with a name like `ITea`. In such a case either the concrete class name is not specific enough, or the abstraction name is not general enough.